# python asyncio fails to concurrently run two infinite functions

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am been trying to run two functions simultaneously but one never seems to work unless I stop the other. The first function sends an email every 30 seconds while the second prints a simple statement every 5 seconds. In combination, per every 6 "Hello Worlds" outputs one email should be sent.

However, I never get an email unless the printing is changed to stop early, such as ending after 10 seconds. What can I do to have both running concurrently without stopping?

```
async def timer():
    end = time.time() + 30
    while True:
        if time.time() >= end:
            sendmail(name, filepath + "\\" + name, receiver)
            end = time.time() + 30

async def runs():
    while True:
        print("Hello World")
        time.sleep(5)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(runs())
loop.create_task(timer())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: ``async`` provides *cooperative* concurrency. ``timer`` is not written cooperatively - it never suspends, e.g. via ``asyncio.sleep(0)``.

Comment: Ideally you'd also want an awaitable version of `sendmail`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python's `async` coroutines are meant for *cooperative* concurrency. That means that coroutines must actively allow others to run. For simple cases, use `await asyncio.sleep` to pause the current coroutine and run others.

```py
async def timer():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(30)  # instead of `if time.time() >= end:…`
        sendmail(name, filepath + "\\" + name, receiver)

async def runs():
    while True:
        print("Hello World")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)  # instead of `time.sleep(5)`

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(timer(), runs())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Notably, do not use `time.sleep` – this blocks the entire thread, meaning the current coroutine *as well as the event loop and all other coroutines*, until the sleep is over.
Similarly, avoid any synchronous code with significant runtime – `asyncio` cannot switch to other coroutines while synchronous code runs. If needed, use an `asyncio` helper to run synchronous code in a thread, e.g. [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread) or [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).

```py
async def timer():
    next_run = time.time()
    while True:
        # run blocking function in thread to keep event-loop free
        await asyncio.to_thread(
            sendmail, name, filepath + "\\" + name, receiver
        )
        # pause to run approx every 30 seconds
        await asyncio.sleep(next_run - time.time())
        next_run += 30
```

Comment: so just to clarify, once runs() reaches "await asyncio.sleep(5)" does it switch to the timer() function for 5 seconds?

Comment: Once ``runs`` reaches ``asyncio.sleep(5)``, ``runs`` is suspended for 5 seconds. In the meantime, ``timer`` or other coroutines *may* run if they desire.

Comment: MisterMiyagi, shouldn't the last line be `asyncio.run(asyncio.gather(...))`? The way it's written, an exception in either coroutine will pass silently.

Comment: @user4815162342 ``asyncio.run`` works only with a coroutine; ``asyncio.gather`` provides merely a ``Future``, not a coroutine. The two are not compatible.

Comment: Ouch, I keep forgetting about that (IMHO arbitrary and unnecessary) limitation of `asyncio.run`. The curio/trio concept of requiring coroutines everywhere doesn't work in asyncio where even some of the most basic utilities, like `gather`, return futures. Anyway, thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

You can Use  `await asycio.sleep()` For async wait

```
import asyncio


async def timer():
    while True:
        
        print("email sent")
        await asyncio.sleep(30)


async def runs():
    while True:
        print("Hello World")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(timer())
loop.create_task(runs())
loop.run_forever()
```