# Python Asyncio wait_for decorator

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-decorators

I am trying to write a decorator that calls [asyncio.wait_for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) on the decorated function - the goal is to set a time limit on the decorated function. I expect the decorated function to stop running after time_limit but it does not. The decorator is being called fine but the code just sleeps for 30 seconds instead of being interrupted. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
def await_time_limit(time_limit):

    def Inner(func):
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return await asyncio.wait_for(func(*args, **kwargs), time_limit)
        return wrapper

    return Inner

@await_time_limit(5)
async def whatever 
    time.sleep(30) # this runs to the full 30 seconds and not stopped after 5
end
```

Comment: `asyncio.wait_for` can only cancel asynchronous code. `time.sleep(30)` will block the current coroutine *and the entire event loop* for 30 seconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python asyncio having trouble with running two infinite functions asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62487364)

Answer (score 1):

As we can see in this example here, the problem arises from using `time.sleep` not `asyncio.sleep`, since `time.sleep` will block the thread. You need to be careful not to have any blocking code

```py
import asyncio
import time


def await_time_limit(time_limit):
    def Inner(func):
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return await asyncio.wait_for(func(*args, **kwargs), time_limit)
        return wrapper
    return Inner


@await_time_limit(5)
async def asleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(30) # this runs for only 5 seconds


@await_time_limit(5)
async def ssleep():
    time.sleep(30) # this runs to the full 30 seconds and not stopped after 5


t1 = time.time()
await asleep()
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1) # 5.018370866775513


t1 = time.time()
await ssleep()
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1) # 30.00193428993225
```